# GoLang Copy Command Prepared Statement Not working

Tags: go, amazon-redshift

I am writing a simple Golang based Redshift DataLoader. I have to use Redshift Copy From S3 command as Prepared statement so that I can pass credentials as part of an argument.

I see lib/pq is not parsing the SQL template correctly. Any thoughts would be appreciated

```
    COPY_FROM_S3 = `
    COPY {{.stageTable}}
    FROM $1
    WITH CREDENTIALS AS $2
    DELIMITER $3
    IGNOREBLANKLINES ACCEPTINVCHARS BLANKSASNULL
    EMPTYASNULL ACCEPTANYDATE ESCAPE MAXERROR 50
    STATUPDATE ON
`
  stmt , _ := redshiftDB.Prepare(COPY_FROM_S3)
  stmt.Exec(s3File, awsCreds, delimter)
```

Getting Syntax error

```
panic: pq: syntax error at or near "$1"

goroutine 1 [running]:
```

Answer (score 0):

lib/pq is indeed parsing it correctly, the problem is you're creating an invalid query template, first: `{{.stageTable}}` is for formal [templates](https://golang.org/pkg/text/template/), second: dollars (**$1**) notation doesn't work for table names in **FROM** statement and not sure if the other **$**s will work

Comment: Well, template string is my first pass, when statement.Exec invoked- Copy command will not have {{. stageTable}} substring. Template gets parsed and substituted with a table name.